# Why does gedit randomly not maintain/apply preferences?

Tags: gedit

Most of the time when I open a file it uses the preferences I set (line numbers, spaces for tabs, etc.) but the occasional file just starts with reset preferences.  Is this a bug, or some weird feature I don't understand?  All the files in question are .py BTW.